# subprocess.check_output ignoring euid

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.5, setuid

I have the following bash script:

```
echo "$(id -u)"
mkdir test
```

My own user id is 1000. Now, when I run python3.5 without root rights and invoke the script via `subprocess.check_output` the script works as expected and creates a folder which is owned by me.
However, when I start python with sudo but then use `os.setegid(1000); os.setuid(1000)`, the script outputs 0 and the folder "test" is owned by root. While I get that `echo "$(id -u)"`may be desired behavior, I do not get why this folder is owned by root. Shouldn't the `os.seteuid()` function prevent that?

My exact call is:

```
>>> os.setegid(1000)
>>> os.seteuid(1000)
>>> subprocess.check_output(["/.script.sh"])
```

Which results in the folder "test" being owned by root. Is this desired behavior and if so, is there any way I can start the script as a normal user while still being able to back to root rights in the python script (i.e., not setting the "real" uid?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setegid` only sets the effective group id of the [current process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.setegid). Same with [seteuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.seteuid).

`check_output` spawns a new process, which is still apparently still run as root.
You might have more luck if you attempt to create your folder [using python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) instead of shelling out to do it, but I imagine this is a simpified example so that may not be appropriate. Is it possible to run the python script as the expected user? If not you might need to do something like this;

```
subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "-uexpected_user", "./script.sh"])
```